# Is there a way to set a multiline description using the p4change Ant task?

Tags: ant, perforce

When I try the following:

```
  <exec executable="ls" outputproperty="aoeu"/>
  <p4change description='${aoeu}'/>
  <echo message='${p4.change}'/>
```

it seems p4change fails silently and the above outputs:

```
 [echo] ${p4.change}
```

Is there a way to set a multiline description using the p4change Ant task?

FWIW, we're using Ant 1.8.2 and Perforce Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2010.2/284433 (2011/01/28).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good luck using the P4Ant library directly from Perforce.

Here's my sample script:

```
<project name="p4ant-job" default="p4tasktest" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Perforce task test
    </description>

    <property name="p4.client" value="bruno_ws"/>
    <property name="p4.port" value="localhost:5000"/>
    <property name="p4.user" value="bruno"/>
    <property name="p4.passwd" value="brunopass"/>

    <taskdef resource="com/perforce/p4java/ant/tasks/P4Tasks.properties"
        classpath="p4ant-2010.1.293250.jar;p4java-2010.1.269249.jar" />

    <target name="p4tasktest" description="Perforce task test">
        <exec executable="ls" outputproperty="mydesc"/>
        <echo>${mydesc}</echo>
        <p4jchange
            description="${mydesc}"
            property="mycl">
        </p4jchange>
        <echo>Created ${mycl}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a perforce guy, but others might find useful the software versions you are using  (ANT and Perforce).

Googling found the following bug:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33260

And the following mail discussion

- http://markmail.org/message/ljglmkzffjdvswta